# Get file path from askopenfilename function in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am writing a script to automate changing a particular set of text in one file into a particular set in another with a different name.

I want to get the name of the file using the `askopenfilename` function, but when I try to print the file name, it returns:

`<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/home/rest/of/file/path/that/I/actually/need.txt' mode='w' encoding='ANSI_X3.4-1968'>`

I need just the file name because the `<_io.TextIOWrapper ...>` is not sub scriptable.

Any suggestions to remove the extraneous bits?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`askopenfilename()` returns the path of the selected file or empty string if no file is selected:

```
from tkinter import filedialog as fd

filename = fd.askopenfilename()
print(len(filename))
```

To open the file selected with `askopenfilename`, you can simply use normal Python constructs and functions, such as the [*`open`*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function:

```
if filename:
    with open(filename) as file:
        return file.read()
```

I think you are using `askopenfile`, which opens the file selected and returns a `_io.TextIOWrapper` object or `None` if you press the *cancel* button.

If you want to stick with `askopenfile` to get the file path of the file just opened, you can simply access the property called `name` of the `_io.TextIOWrapper` object returned:

```
file = fd.askopenfile()
if file: 
    print(file.name)
```

If you want to know more about all the functions defined under the `filedialog` (or `tkFileDialog` for Python 2) module, you can read [*this article*](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/tkFileDialog).

Comment: Hi link to article is broken do you have the new one ? cheers

Comment: @pippo1980 Try to search for a cached version of it on webarchive.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20170515140020/http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/tkFileDialog